# Using vscode for oneAPI can't find "CL/sycl.hpp"

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, intel-oneapi

I have installed the oneAPI on the Linux server.And it runs well when I use command `icpx -fsycl test.cpp -o test` to compile source file.
Now I use vscode on Windows to connect to the server, but it can't find the head file correctly.
[Error message here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrRNu.png)
And my `c_cpp_properties.json` file set as below:[c_cpp_properties.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INFyq.png)
I mainly want to use vscode's code prompts and completion to edit.

Could you tell me how to solve the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing this issue because of problems with your SSH connection in Visual Studio or due to driver issues.
To fix this, please refer to the below link,

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/user-guide-vs-code/2023-0/using-visual-studio-code-with-remote-intel-oneapi.html

Please try to download OpenCL sdk from the below link, https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/opencl-sdk/choose-download.html